# Dotnet undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: .net, ubuntu

Upgraded  VM to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and after that I am experiencing the below error when running the dotnet test.

```
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet: symbol lookup error: /opt/devops-agent/_work/1/s/apps/tests/service/Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE.
```

Please help
dotnet --version
6.0.116